# Puppeteer - Element doesn't appear on the screen

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

When I start Puppeteer in NodeJS to take a photo of Google Flights page, one element doesn't appear (when the browser is started with Puppeteer) but when I use the same URL/link and open it as usual with any other browser (without Puppeteer) I can see that element.

I kinda understand that Google flights probably render HTML on client-side, and not SSR. But it is weird why I can't see just this element.

This is the URL I'm using to test: [Click](https://www.google.com/flights#flt=MIA./m/05qtj.2019-10-14*/m/05qtj.MIA.2019-10-18;c:GBP;e:1;sd:1;t:f)

My code:

```
const screenShot = (url) => {

  return new Promise( async (resolve) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0 });
    await page.screenshot({ path: "screenshot.png" });

    browser.close();
    resolve("Done");

  });
}
```

This is the element which doesn't appear when I run Chrome/Chromium with Puppeteer:

http://prntscr.com/pe6agz

Answer (score 0):

## Problem: Region

You need to select a country/region first. Probably because of regional differences. Make sure you are using the program from right country.

[image]

Also, the element you highlighted (most probably) is visible only if you are visiting from the same country as your target. This showed when I filtered from USA and visited from USA IP.
[image]

However, this showed when I visited from another country,
[image]

*So there are some hidden rules applied from Google Flights, sadly you cannot do anything about it right now, until someone finds some exploits.*

## Problem: `waitUntil: 'load'`

You are not waiting for page to finish load.

waitUntil: 'load' won't wait till all elements are loaded on the page. It will resolve when the HTML loads. So you need to wait for the requests to finish.

Use `waitUntil: 'networkidle0'` or `waitUntil: 'networkidle2'` to make sure most of the requests are finished. Read more about [on the docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.20.0/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options).

```
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0 });
```

Comment: Did you succeed to make this work in NodeJS? I selected the language English, country USA and tried to find the flights from LA to NY, I wasn't able to see the element when I run it with puppeteer and Chromium in `headless: false` mode?

Comment: This is most probably a flight condition google applies to specific route and country.